# LUKS encryption full disk, how many RAM?

Tags: linux, debian, encryption

If I encrypt (dm crypt, LUKS) my whole system, how many RAM should I provide ?

I've understood that LUKS volume is mounted RAM, ... If my system is 10 Gb, should I have something like RAM 12 Go ?

Comment: LUKS is an encryption layer. It usually sits on top of a physical disk, so the amount of memory (RAM) in your system is largely irrelevant. (Unless you're on an embedded system, I suppose, where memory is often very tight.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have misunderstood. The LUKS data is stored on disc and encrypted/decrypted a block at a time as necessary (of course there is some caching going on).

I don't know the minimum size, but I operated a 32Gb LUKS encrypted ReiserFS partition from a 1 GB memory PC. A whole disc shouldn't make any difference from using LUKS on a partition.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I was asking based on this schema, http://blog.theglu.org/public/.schema_m.jpg (french language). Ok. Thanks. Do you confirm the system run as not encrypted, unless some added slowness ? If I add files - downloads as a client - , serve files, serve local web, etc...

Comment: I used this for my homedirectory (email, files, download etc). Yes of course there is overhead, but with a multicore system this is IMO acceptable. As far as my French goes that description doesn't say you would need more memory than encrypted disc either.

Comment: Thanks. I 'll go this way. I'll encrypt a new install of Mint. Then I'll configure it. And finally I'll clone it to my virgin machines.

Comment: FYI @ArchiT3K Depending on how you clone your disk, you may end up copying the same LUKS master encryption key to every virgin machine's disk, so even if you add or delete passphrases, any user on any machine could decrypt any other machine's drive. Doing a fresh luksFormat on each new drive, then copying over the decrypted data would avoid that.

Comment: @Xen2050 : thanks. Very clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

cryptsetup shipped by debian has preconfigured default pbkdf argon2i for luks2 with memory requirement of 1G. This memory is used during the decryption of the master key each time before a volume is mounted. Then this memory is released, and afterwards the memory overhead is minimal. In memory constraind environment you may set this memory requirement to lower, or use other algorithm.

Comment: That's why starting the machine with 1024MB ram throws "Out of memory" exception: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFGdA.png